# UWP Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer: Will this handle physical DVDs (copy protected)

Tags: c#, uwp, media-player, dvd

I've been googling and don't see where MediaPlayer even handles DVDs.

Can anybody point me to any docs or a sample for playing a DVD, or is this something that has been dropped?

The API looks pretty complete, but I don't see any way to point it to an actual device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DVD and BluRay playback is not available in uwp api yet. you have to wait for this feature to be part of SDK only then it can be applied to your app.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's why I couldn't find it. 8-). It's just such a basic feature, I assumed it was there and I was just missing it.

Comment: I agree with you, this is a feature I also want for my app. but unfortunately it isnt available yet.